# CSS: How to select elements by referencing the parent, not the child

Tags: css, css-selectors

Let's say I have several `<p>` elements inside a `<div>` like this:

HTML

```
<div>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p> <!-- I want to select the "last" element, <p> or not <p> -->
</div>
```

Now, say I want to style the last element, `<p>` or not `<p>`. One way to do that is to use the `last-child` selector on the `<p>`'s like this:

CSS

```
<style>
  p:last-child {
    /* Awesome styles go here */
  }
</style>
```

## Question

> **How do I style the last element (`<p>` or not `<p>`) by referencing `<div>` but NOT `<p>`?**

### Live Code Example

```css
p:last-child {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Bar</p>
  <p>Baz</p> <!-- I want to select the "last" element, <p> or not <p> -->
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Any use-case? You will have to select a element inside the div. If you want to avoid a child selection, it is not possible with CSS. But you can make use of `*` selector to select any element.

Comment: If you want to select a p element, you have to include p in your selector. Otherwise how is the browser going to know you're looking for a p element?

Comment: @boltclock: Read the answer. The wildcard selector `*` is the solution.

Comment: It's the solution if you're looking for the last child whether it is a p or some other element. But that's not what your question is asking. You should edit it so future readers don't get confused.

Comment: @BoltClock: Point taken. Good catch. I edited the question accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `>` in your selector to describe direct children:

```
div > p:last-child {
}
```

This CSS will affect only the `p` tags which are the last child of `div` tag.

If, for some reason, you don't want to reference `p` at all, you can use `*` selector:

```
div > *:last-child {
}
```

It will affect the last child of the `div` whatever it is.

**For example:**

```css
div > *:last-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>    
</div>

<div>
  <a href="#">1</a>
  <a href="#">2</a>
  <a href="#">3</a>    
</div>

<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <i>2</i>
  <i>3</i> 
</div>
```

Comment: But he does not want to include `p` in the selection.

Comment: @manoj: Correct. I do not want to have to use the `<p>` because that can be a variable.